# We're no longer sketchy; someone should update the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

Now that the beta sites have moved on from the sketchy theme, the FAQs should be updated to no longer answer "Why does this site look so 'sketchy'?"

Apparently this needs to be done at a [network-wide level](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/3244).

Comment: I think it has been done. The FAQ is showing screen shots from The Great Outdoors now (it used to be Bicycles)

Comment: "Why does this site look so grainy?"

Comment: @ChrisF—I'm not sure if I follow; I know at least the rpg faq still references sketchy.

Comment: @DanRasmussen I think ChrisF was talking about the images(which have been updated to the new theme from Sketchy). Your question is about the paragraph of text that mentions Sketchy. Yes, it will be removed or re-worded soon.

Comment: @Jin - Ah thanks for the clarification